# How to read the app settings (from iPhone Settings app) when app is launched

Tags: iphone, cocoa, ios

How can read the app settings when app is launched? For instance, for some gaming application, you set the sound, vibration setting in iPhone Settings app. So, how to read those settings when that gaming app is launched?

Comment: Look through the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Preferences/Preferences.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are set as a 'Settings.bundle'; the iOS Application Programming guide [shows how to implement this in your app.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Preferences/Preferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW5)

Answer (score 0):

In your appDelegate, in the didFinishLaunching function, retrieve your settings. See [User Defaults Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/UserDefaults.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i), particularly the information about NSUserDefaults.